# script for clicking link in QTP/UFT

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am currently stuck at a place while writing a script for clicking a link on a page using VB Script in QTP.
Please guide how to achieve this. Any help will be highly appreciated. I am stuck here and cannot proceed further.

Comment: To answer this best, you'll have to give a little more context. What code do you have now that isn't working? Is anything similar working? Is there something different between the link you're trying to click and others you've successfully clicked before?

Answer (score 1):

For that you can write descriptive or directly drag and drop that link from OR and add event in the last for click.

For example:

```
Browser("Google").Page("Google Search").Link("Help").Click
```